# 'Profile' object is not callable

Tags: django

TypeError at /accounts/signup/
'Profile' object is not callable

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("review:index")

    if request.method == "POST":
        signup_form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)

        if signup_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = signup_form.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            Profile.objects.create(
                user=user,
                nickname=profile.nickname,
            )

            auth_login(
                request,
                user,
            )
            return redirect("review:index")
    else:
        signup_form = CustomUserCreationForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()

    context = {
        "signup_form": signup_form,
        "profile_form": profile_form,
    }

    return render(request, "accounts/signup.html", context)
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
         .....

class Profile(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, null=True)
          .......
```

**forms.py**

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = [
            "username",
            "password1",
            "password2",
        ]

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile()
        fields = [
            "nickname",
                 ........
        ]
```

In the process of filling out the signup form, I wanted to put the nickname data in profile.nickname.

But 'Profile' object is not callable. A TypeError is raised.

Comment: Please tag your question with the correct technology that is used, so that those familiar with these technologies get to see it. This doesn't look like it has much to do with HTML. I assume you are using some Python framework here? Please [edit] the question to add that framework as a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form, `model = Profile()` creates an object. You just need to provide a class:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "nickname",
                 ........
        ]
```